# Software that logs when I'm working

Tags: windows, time-management, logs

I'm looking for a Windows software that records when I am working with the PC.

It should log when the PC is started and shut down. Also it should check every few minutes if the screen is on or if there is some activity.

I would prefer a simple VBS script file (without GUI) that writes into a plain text log file.

(I know [Grindstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grindstone_(time-tracking_software)), but I do not like it. When the PC is restarted or crashes or goes into hibernate, it looses records.)

Comment: You added the [tag:open-source] tag, but your question doesn’t mention it. Is the software required to be open source? If yes, please [edit] your question to state this; if no, please remove the tag :)